# Why aren't there simulateous spin z and x eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Consider the spin $1/2$ case and suppose I have an eigenstate of $S_z$. This has $\sigma_z=0$. The uncertainty principle states that $\sigma_z \sigma_x \geq \frac{\hbar}{2} |\langle S_y\rangle|$. In this case $|\langle S_y\rangle|=0$, so the uncertainty principle is obeyed. However, why can't $\sigma_x=0$ too then? I know it doesn't have to be the case just because the uncertainty principle wouldn't prevent it, but I'm wondering if there's some reason related to the principle?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer why $\S_x$ and $\S_z$ can not be simultaneously specified is of course since they do not commute, i.e. $[S_x,S_z]=S_y$. This leads to your uncertainly relation $$\sigma_x\sigma_y\geq\frac\hbar2|\left<S_y\right>|$$

Since in your special case $\left<S_y\right>=0$ you can choose $\sigma_z=0$ without violating the bound. That $\sigma_x\neq0$ is already build in from the start.